# How to find difference between 2 unix timestamps (milliseconds) and convert into human readable format

Tags: javascript, timestamp, momentjs, unix-timestamp

I want to find difference between current time and prev time given in milliseconds(unix time).

Example :
difference(milliseconds) = (12345...)-(12345...)

now how to convert this milliseconds in to human readable format like 10 secs,40 minutes, 10 hours or 2 days or even H:M:S or DD-MM-YYYY H:M:S etc ?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at moment.js?

Comment: yes, i have tried this thing  moment.duration(currentTimestamp.diff(availableTimestamp)).humanize(); but i guess i am doing some mistake here

Comment: currentTimestamp.diff(availableTimestamp,'days') // you can change days to years,seconds,etc.

where

currentTimestamp = moment(1454521239279)//Current timestamp
availableTimestamp = moment(1054511239279)//Available timestamp

Comment: Thanks @FrederickRosales